# Doctrine Entity is missing an assigned ID

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have two Entities, Contact and Global.

```
Example\EventBundle\Entity\EventGlobal:
    type: entity
    table: EventGlobal
       fields:
          id:
              id: true
              type: integer
              generator:
                strategy: AUTO
  oneToOne:
      EventKontakt:
      targetEntity: Example\EventBundle\Entity\EventContact
      mappedBy: EventGlobal
      cascade: ["persist"]



Example\EventBundle\Entity\EventContact:
    type: entity
    table: EventContact
    fields:
      EventGlobal_id:
       id: true
       type: integer
      oneToOne:
        EventGlobal:
         targetEntity: Example\EventBundle\Entity\EventGlobal
         inversedBy: EventContact
         joinColumns:
           EventGlobal_id:
             referencedColumnName: id
             nullable: false
```

They are working fine. Now i build a Form with Symfony

```
        public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(Stuff..)
        ->add('EventContact', new EventContactType($this->options))
    ;
}
```

The Form is correctly rendered, with its one-to-one relation.
But when i save i get an error.

and my Error is:

```
    Entity of type Example\EventBundle\Entity\EventContact is missing an assigned ID. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.
```

How can i achive that my safing is done by Symfony/Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add generator for the EventContact.

for your EventContact entity.

```
fields:
   EventGlobal_id:
   id: true
   type: integer
   generator:
       strategy: AUTO
```

Comment: It works partly, if i only generate a eventglobal without eventcontact once, and then return to generate boths the id is broken and links to the last entry.